# Submitting jQuery.each results via ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
$(".submitinfo").each(function() {
  // Want to use ID as POST name
  // And value as POST value
});
// Submit the data
$.ajax({
  url: 'submit.php',
  traditional: true,
  data: {
  'submit':'true',
  'age':$('#age').val(),
  'loss':$('#loss').val()
      // somehow include results here
},
type: 'POST',
async: false,
success: function(data) {
  alert(data);

},
error: function() {
  alert('Submit Error');
}
});
```

I've never had to do this before, and can't find any examples of it anywhere. I have a series of inputs with a class of submitinfo that I would like to be able to submit alongside other inputs via an ajax request. How can I do this? Check the code comments for details.

Thanks!

Comment: You absolutely never want to use a synchronous Ajax request. You should set `async: true`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an object, and add the values in the `each` function to the object, and pass that object to `$.ajax` as data :

```
var data = {
  submit : 'true',
  age    : $('#age').val(),
  loss   : $('#loss').val()
 }

$(".submitinfo").each(function() {
    data[this.id]=this.value;
});

$.ajax({
  url: 'submit.php',
  traditional: true,
  data: data,
  type: 'POST',
  async: false,
  success: function(data) {
    alert(data);
  },
  error: function() {
    alert('Submit Error');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're trying to submit a form via ajax.

The javascript idiom I use for this is a lot shorter and simpler. In short, you serialize the form jquery object using the [serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) function. This puts it in an ajax-friendly format. You can then send this directly to [$.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/). The name attribute of the form elements correspond to request parameter names on the server side.

```
$.post(url, $('form').serialize(), function(data) {
    alert("Success");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for you:

```
var data = {};
$('.submitinfo').each(function() {
    var el = $(this),
        id = el.attr('id'),
        val = el.val();

    data[id] = val;
}); 

$.ajax({
  url: 'submit.php',
  traditional: true,
  data: data,
  type: 'POST',
  async: false,
  success: function(data) {
    alert(data);
  },
  error: function() {
    alert('Submit Error');
  }
});
```